# SQL count by column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I'm trying to count multiple values in multiple coluns in a table and I did that:

TABLE

| id | risk | record | api |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OK | OK | NO |
| 2 | OK | OK | OK |
| 3 | OK | OK | OK |
| 4 | OK | NO | OK |
| 5 | NO | OK | NO |

SQL:

```
select 'risk' as nm_test, risk as tst_result, count(*) as qty 
  from table
  group by risk 

union 

select 'record' as nm_test, record as tst_result, count(*) as qty
  from table
  group by record

union

select 'api' as nm_test, api as tst_result, count(*) as qty
  from table
  group by api
```

The result is the following table:

| nm_test | tst_result | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| risk | OK | 4 |
| risk | NO | 1 |
| record | OK | 4 |
| record | NO | 1 |
| api | OK | 3 |
| api | NO | 2 |

But, instead, I would like to have the result table pivoted like this:

| nm_test | OK | NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| risk | 4 | 1 |
| record | 4 | 1 |
| api | 3 | 2 |

I tried to do that, but I was unable to figure out the trick! Any help would be valuable.

Cheers.

Comment: That's called "pivoting". In SQL you probably need to know in advance the number of columns to show. Is that a fixed list, like "OK" and "NO" only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed columns to pivot, and values are 'OK' and 'NO' only then :

```
select 'risk' as nm_test, 
        count(case when risk = 'OK' then 1 end) as 'OK',
        count(case when risk = 'NO' then 1 end) as 'NO'
from mytable
union all
select 'record', 
        count(case when record = 'OK' then 1 end),
        count(case when record = 'NO' then 1 end)
from mytable
union all
select 'api', 
        count(case when api = 'OK' then 1 end),
        count(case when api = 'NO' then 1 end)
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DCLW_vIh)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  nm_test,
  SUM(CASE WHEN tst_result = 'OK' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS OK,
  SUM(CASE WHEN tst_result = 'NO' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS NO
FROM (
  SELECT 'risk' AS nm_test, risk AS tst_result, COUNT(*) AS qty
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY risk

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'record' AS nm_test, record AS tst_result, COUNT(*) AS qty
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY record

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'api' AS nm_test, api AS tst_result, COUNT(*) AS qty
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY api
) subquery
GROUP BY nm_test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget using `UNION`.

Pivoting from columns to rows in PostgreSQL can be done by casting into and out of `jsonb`.  This helps if you will be adding more tests in the future.

```
with pivot as (
  select j.*
    from mytable
   cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(mytable) - 'id') 
                        as j(nm_test, tst_result)
)
select nm_test, 
       count(*) filter (where tst_result = 'OK') as ok,
       count(*) filter (where tst_result = 'NO') as no
  from pivot
 group by nm_test;
```

Using  `- id` gets rid of that column from the results.

Using `filter` on the aggregates pivots back to columns.  This is useful so long as the possible results are finite and known.

[Working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/PKOgeBza).